# Recover an oVirt Hosted Engine Crash

Tags: virtualization, ovirt

I have an oVirt setup, and recently yum updated all packages in hosts and hosted engine.

Problem is I can't start the hosted engine. After a while if you issue the command:

```
hosted-engine --vm-status
```

You get:

```
--== Host 1 status ==--

Status up-to-date                  : True
Hostname                           : hyper1.sarmiento.dmsn
Host ID                            : 1
Engine status                      : {"reason": "bad vm status", "health": "bad", "vm": "down", "detail": "down"}
Score                              : 0
Local maintenance                  : False
Host timestamp                     : 4129
Extra metadata (valid at timestamp):
    metadata_parse_version=1
    metadata_feature_version=1
    timestamp=4129 (Tue May  5 13:15:28 2015)
    host-id=1
    score=0
    maintenance=False
    state=EngineUnexpectedlyDown
    timeout=Wed Dec 31 22:14:34 1969


--== Host 2 status ==--

Status up-to-date                  : True
Hostname                           : hyper2.sarmiento.dmsn
Host ID                            : 2
Engine status                      : {"reason": "bad vm status", "health": "bad", "vm": "down", "detail": "down"}
Score                              : 0
Local maintenance                  : False
Host timestamp                     : 3900
Extra metadata (valid at timestamp):
    metadata_parse_version=1
    metadata_feature_version=1
    timestamp=3900 (Tue May  5 13:15:19 2015)
    host-id=2
    score=0
    maintenance=False
    state=EngineUnexpectedlyDown
    timeout=Wed Dec 31 22:11:48 1969
```

I've been serching a lot in the logs, and what seems to be the problem is that in

```
/var/log/libvirt/qemu/HostedEngine.log
```

I can see

```
2015-05-05T15:18:29.928875Z qemu-kvm: -drive file=/var/run/vdsm/storage/fa0ae001-ccaf-46ed-940a-a3bb1f147f18/c1cd16d1-068d-467b-88fd-6a4910099d27/51e3c614-7725-429d-b1b6-99dbe4eb3b7c,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,format=raw,serial=c1cd16d1-068d-467b-88fd-6a4910099d27,cache=none,werror=stop,rerror=stop,aio=threads: could not open disk image /var/run/vdsm/storage/fa0ae001-ccaf-46ed-940a-a3bb1f147f18/c1cd16d1-068d-467b-88fd-6a4910099d27/51e3c614-7725-429d-b1b6-99dbe4eb3b7c: Could not refresh total sector count: Operation not permitted
2015-05-05 15:18:30.183+0000: shutting down
```

It says that it cannot open the image file. But it does not says why!!! Any idea on how to debug this and have the engine up and running again???

Thanks a lot!!

Edit: oVirt Version is 3.5

Comment: What storage do you use? Have you run diagnostics on the disk image for the VM?

Comment: The engine uses a gluster NFS export. I don't know how to run duagnostics on the image! How would you do that?

Comment: `qemu-img info` and `qemu-img check` would do, to start with. If they pass, go over the file permissions. Since this is gluster based, also check that side of things

Comment: Ok... I'm getting Input/output error when I run qemu-img on the file. But how can I get to the source of this problem??? It's probably something with Gluster I think... or maybe it's a lock issue???

Comment: So, the image is either corrupted or inaccessible, start debugging gluster first (and that's a totally different issue really)

Comment: Ok! I'll do that. Basically I will try to mount the share from another location and try to write and read a file. If that's OK, how can i know if the image is locked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23500/discussion-between-luciano-cesar-natale-and-dyasny).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it was a storage issue. Hosted engine images was hosted by a gluster volume and the image was in a split-brain situation.

Thanks dyasny for your help!!!